# I want to save the form info on a div so that it stays on the page when its refreshed

Tags: php, html, database

I want to save the form data, that's transformed to a php (I already got that part, its designed and styled in css) I want to save it so that the form is available on a page for everyone to see, so that when I refresh the page, the div that has the form info stays there.

```
<form name = "quoted" form action="genericwebpage.html" method="post">
<input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">   <br>
<textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote"placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
 <input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>
```

and here's the php found on the webpage it's going to.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
    <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
    <div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_GET['actual-quote']?></div>
    <div class="poster"><?php echo $_GET['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions, is EXTREMELY welcomed.
Thanks!
-Connor

Comment: If the method is post, your should use $_POST instead of $_GET

Comment: do you mean you want to save the data in database first and then display it for all users by fetching the submitted data from batabase?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change $_GET to $_POST because your form has a post method. That should make it so that when the form is submitted, the data will be displayed in the div where you have it being echoed. However, that will only be temporary ... it won't be anywhere for "everyone to see" unless you save it in a database.

Answer (score -1):

You hav to use Local Storage or Server Side Scripting (eg PHP).

Comment: store form info into cookie or session, display it back when it is reloaded.

Comment: You're not focusing. 1) Why cookies and sessions? 2) I'm not the OP.